# TreeView MouseLeave event fires when moves over ScrollBar

Tags: .net, scrollbar, mouseleave, mouseenter

In the TreeView, ListBox, or it seems from my google searches anything with a ScrollBar, the ScrollBar is not considered a part of the control.

I have a TreeView that I'm putting into a custom control, and it's Dock Fill. So there it acts as a custom TreeView which has all our logic to manage it in one place.

In parts of our program we slide it out based on a MouseEnter event, and slide it back in on a MouseLeave event, however we are currently using a 3rd party library's TreeView for this, which I have been tasked with replacing.

So I've moved everything over to the Windows TreeView, but can not find a way to reliable capture the MouseLeave -only- if it leaves the entire TreeView, scrollbar included.

I've seen one hackish solution of wrapping it in a panel with several pixels and capturing the MouseLeave of the panel, but I hardly believe this is what Microsoft had intended us to do in this situation.

**In Short:**

**The ScrollBar does not fire MouseEnter or MouseLeave for the control, and that makes using MouseEnter/MouseLeave for sliding out the control unusable since the user can not use the ScrollBar.**

What is the preferred way to handle this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fire up Spy++ and select the Treeview window.  Move the mouse on the scrollbar.  Plenty of activity there, WM_NCMOUSEMOVE looks like a good one to me.  Catch it in a WndProc() override.

Comment: This is .net, don't have access to WndProc or WM_NCMOUSEMOVE

Comment: Sure you do, WndProc() is a method of the TreeView class that you can overload in your own derived class.  WM_NCMOUSEMOVE is a number, it is 0xa0.  Check the MSDN docs.

Answer (score 1):

Put a panel with the exact size of the ListBox including the Scrollbar under the Listbox.
Then put mouseleave event on panel.